# IIS7 redirection best practices

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl

I am looking for the "best practice" way of secure site redirection with IIS7 and ASP.net.
Say I have two domain names:

- mydomain.com
- mydomain.net

each with a www subdomain.

I have a single EV certificate that uses the common name:

- www.mydomain.com

Therefore, the user can access the site 8 different possible ways:

```
- http://mydomain.com
- http://mydomain.net
- http://www.mydomain.com
- http://www.mydomain.net
- and also using https://
```

In order for the user to not receive certificate errors, he/she must be directed to

```
 - https://www.mydomain.com
```

What is the best way to make this work transparently to the user while still ensuring that IIS serves up only secure content? In the past I have used web.config to redirect to a sub page like this:

```
<system.webServer>

<httpRedirect destination="https://www.mydomain.com/secureSubPage" />
```

or with wildcard certificates using this block in a common base page:

```
 if (!Request.IsSecureConnection)
    {
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"), true);
        return;
    }
    if (!Request.Url.ToString().Contains(".com"))
    {
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString().Replace(".net", ".com"), true);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: This question may be better suited for the "sister site" at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `UrlRewrite`, I use it for sub-domains all the time:

[Automatically Redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS on IIS 7 using URL Rewrite 2.0](http://www.jppinto.com/2010/03/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis7-using-url-rewrite-2-0/)